# Graphics creative commons for video game

Tags: graphics

i'm looking for "graphics elements" like sprite of cars, human movement etc. using for a game open source made with pygame. 
Anyone know if exists a web site providing this service ?
Thank you and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check out http://www.openclipart.org/ All their graphics are in SVG format so you can size them how you like. It's all public domain, so no licensing issues. Not sure if they have the particular images you need, but it is the site you're looking for.